# change max file uploads in php

Tags: php, file-upload, max

When I check in phpinfo() in a browser, my max_file_uploads (images in my case) is set to 20, but I need to change that to a higher limit. Supposedly this is to be changed in the php.ini but I couldn't find anything that would relate to it.

Help please! Thanks a lot!!

edit: tried to add the line max_file_uploads = 100 since there was no such line in the php.ini, but it didn't do the trick. also the "100" is red, i don't know if that means something...

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for help _with_.

Comment: Do a find on `max_file_uploads` in the PHP.INI mentioned on you `phpinfo()` output. If its not there add one like this `max_file_uploads = 30`

Comment: thx a lot for your reply, yeah it's not there, so i just add it?

Comment: i edited my question and added an image of what the file uploads bit of my php.ini looks like..

Comment: make sure you restart the webserver after making changes to the php.ini

Comment: after restarting the server (local in my case) the adding of max_file_uploads=100 has taken effect and it now works, thanks to everyone! i'll summarise the different inputs into one answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache web server, here is a solution that does not require editing php.ini:

Create a .htaccess file if one does not exist already and add the following line to it.

```
php_value max_file_uploads 100
```

Where 100 is the maximum number of files allowed. You can change it to the desired integer value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RiggsFolly and Jeff Puckett II I could make it work as follows:

If the line "max_file_uploads" is already in the php.ini but the number is insufficient, change the number and restart the web- or local server. done.

If the line "max_file_uploads" doesn't exist yet, just add it, restart the web- or local server. done.